# Install4j: Script builder?

Tags: java, bash, batch-file, install4j

Is there a native function to install4j that will allow me to generate a very basic run script for the services that only include the Java invocation and not all the other hooks the startup script provides? Our developers have requested this because the Windows console script is a binary and not a batch script.

My current solution would be to just take the information that was given during the installation and generate a script based upon that but then I run into compatibility across different platforms - specifically Windows batch.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 6.0.3, there is no such built-in functionality.

Comment: Ingo, I've stuck to manually generating mine but the only problem I am having is obtaining what is in the class path for a launcher. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need .install4j/i4jruntime.jar and all the entries that you have defined in the "Java invocation" step of the launcher wizard.